# Updating parameter file in informatica

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

I am updating the parameter file with the workflow variable as part of the post session success command in informatica. This session runs twice in the workflow once in the beginning and again at the end. When it runs for the first time the command is executing successfully but I can’t see the value being replaced in the parameter file but when it runs at the end the value is being replaced correctly. Any idea what causing this issue. I need the parameter file to updated in the beginning so there are other sessions in between that uses this parameter file. Any suggestions or alternatives please.

Comment: Can you give more details how its set ? Is it system or user defined variable? How you're changing it - command or some auto logic? Depending on how you set it up it can show old value and get updated upon completion

Comment: I am updating with sed command in the post session command component.when it runs for the first time I can see a new parameter file is being generated but the parameter value is not set but when it runs at the end the parameter value is replaced even though the value is passed correctly even the first time, can see that value in the session log.

Comment: so the sed command seems like not working properly. what is the command you are using in first post session?

Comment: Actually I missed a point, the sed command worked fine but I am calling a script in between that flow and the script is also replacing the parameter file and that’s when I am loosing the mapping variable value, removed that from the script and it’s working fine, thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

If you specify a parameterfile for a workflow, here's what happens:

1. Workflow starts, parameter file is read as part of workflow initialization and parameter values are set
2. Session runs
3. Post session command is triggered, but parameters are not updated anymore. This happens as p. 1 only!
4. Further processing with values set at point 1.

If you need to change the parameters during workflow run, please specify Session parameter files. This way Session 1 can generate values for another session to use. Set the value at Session -> Properties -> Parameter File.